# Estou tentando executar um programa com contagem regressiva , porem no counter ele nao esta diminuindo

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int counter, number_1, number_2;
    string resposta, resposta_2, responder, responder_2, resp = "lol";
    bool verdadeiro = true;


    while (verdadeiro) {

        cout << "A) Executar um pequeno quiz\n" << "B) Sair do programa\n";
        cin >> resposta;


        if (resposta == "A") {
            resposta_2 = "true";
            counter = 10;

        }


        else if (resposta == "B") {
            verdadeiro = false;
        }


        while (resposta != "A" && resposta != "B") {
            cout << "digite novamente apenas A ou B\n";
            cin >> resposta;

            if (resposta == "A") {
                resposta_2 = "true";
                counter = 10;

            }

            else if (resposta == "B") {
                verdadeiro = false;
            }
        }

        while (resposta_2 == "true") {

            while (counter > 0) {

                counter--; // Faz a contagem regressiva(porem nao esta funcionando)
                Sleep(1000);
                cout << counter;

                if (counter == 0) { // E volta para o menu inicial
                    resposta_2 = "false";
                }

                cout << "Em que ano teve inicio a 2 guera mundial?\n";
                cin >> responder;



                if (responder == "1939") {
                    cout << "Muito bem acertou , o quiz acabou deseja sair do programa ou voltar par o menu?\n";

                }

                else {
                    cout << "Errou acabou o jogo\n";
                    counter = 0;
                    resposta_2 = "Nao";
                }

                cout << "Digite Sim para voltar ao menu principal ou Nao para sair\n";
                cin >> responder_2;
                while (responder_2 != "Sim" && responder_2 != "Nao") {
                    cout << "Digite apenas Sim ou Nao\n";
                    cin >> responder_2;
                    if (responder_2 == "Sim") {
                        counter = 0;
                        resposta_2 = "false";
                    }
                    if (responder_2 == "Nao") {
                        counter = 0;
                        resposta_2 = "false";
                        verdadeiro = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tente encapsular a lógica em um for: `for (i=counter, i>0, i--)`

Comment: Tentei mas tb nao deu.

Comment: Thomson, o contador decrescente indica 10 tentativas para acertar a pergunta? Se sim por que você define para 0 (zero) o contador após uma resposta errada. Desta forma você quebra a lógica que você mesmo criou logo acima e não repete 10 vezes o código. Na verdade o loop só é executado uma vez pois acertando ou errando a resposta você termina o jogo.

Answer (score -2):

Quando você digitar sim ou não acontece nada, pois você não colocou uma condição para travar o loop (counter > 0). E quando você digita algo diferente de "**sim**"/"**não**" entra no loop

```
while (responder_2 != "Sim" && responder_2 != "Nao")
```

Use o operador lógico OU (||) para travar o loop, sugiro usar um **break**;